# How to deploy a meteor application to my website

Tags: meteor

I've downloaded telescope from github and I'm trying to install it on my website.
unfortunately I don't know how? I tried it on my mac with no problems

```
git clone git@github.com:TelescopeJS/Telescope.git
```

And

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Comment: Did you tried the same? Does anything happens when you use that command?

Comment: got error, command not found

Comment: Are you in Mac, now?

Comment: yes! i'm using yosemite

Comment: Have you read http://www.telesc.pe/docs/deploying/ ?

Comment: Which part worked, and which part errored? Post your error if you got one. You may not have the `curl` executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy use meteor deploy to deploy to the meteor servers. 
Look at mup by arunoda for deploying to your own server. 
There's also demetorizer.

Comment: Agree with @Eliezer, for example: `meteor deploy your-site-name.meteor.com` and they will take care of hosting it in a basic way for you.